# Can I use only Ruby or Crystal Lang with an Arduino?

Tags: programming

I am new to Arduino. I have used other SBCs before and ran some ruby script to automate many tasks.

I know Ruby and Crystal programming languages.

Can I use Ruby or Crystal solely on Arduino for creating basic robot?

Comment: Short answer: No

Comment: Long answer: Noooooooooooooo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could bridging via Firmata: https://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/Ruby/

Another resource is https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/using-ruby-to-program-arduino--cms-21893

You will need to Flash your Arduino with Firmata and then program in Ruby.
I'm not sure if that would work with Crystal.

Answer (score 2):

No. You cannot. It is not possible. And some more filler to make the answer long enough.

Answer (score 1):

This is for Ruby:
https://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/Ruby/

Here are generic info about interfacing:
https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/Interfacing/